# While loop not executing with jframe implementation

Tags: java, swing, while-loop

So basically I have a public static void main method that creates a frame and a level the level is a panel that is then added to the jframe but then after the code does not seem to check my while loop that is in the main and I know it doesnt because my while loop should be checked as long as the frame is visible and it should print a line in a console window if it gets to this point and it does not.
Any help would be appreciated! Also yes I know the print line is going to make a console window window pop up and not actually put it in the frame I heave a separate function for this while statement I am just using the println for debugging purposes.

```
public class Main extends JFrame 
{
  public static void main(String[]args)
  {
  System.out.println("LevelStart");
  LevelOne l = new LevelOne();
  //Level Two not made yet just a place holder to show constructor with a different type
  LevelTwo l2 = new LevelTwo();
  //I make l2 first because the front frame is the last one created
  Main m = new Main(l2);
  Main m2 = new Main(l);
  //To switch levels i am going to load them all in advance and then when the beat the level it will close the frame


  while (m2.isVisible())
   {
      System.out.println("If this displays something is wrong with my checkWin method"); 
      if(l.checkWin())
     {
       System.out.println("If this displays something is wrong with my checkWin method");

     }  
    }
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your while loop goes against Swing threading rules and should be removed.

Regardless, you program design should be improved. You shouldn't be creating new JFrame objects, but rather should be creating a JPanel that uses CardLayout, add all the level JPanels to this CardLayout-using JPanel, using unique String constants when adding the levels. Then you can easily swap levels by calling the appropriate CardLayout method, either `next(...)` or `show(...)`

Comment: Even if I was to do it this way which it could easily be adapted for so I will probably do this I still would need to check for my win in the main after I had all the levels to the layout. Wouldint the only difference be that I would have one frame and then instead of disposing each frame to change levels I would show the next panel so wouldint I want to check for my win condition in a similar way?

Comment: `"I still would need to check for my win in the main after I had all the levels to the layout."` -- why? That's a terrible design. The main method should just start the GUI then move out of the way. Your code suggests that you don't yet fully understand event-driven GUI programming.

Comment: @RichieZ: you would check for "win condition" by listening for events that might cause it to occur. The last thing you'd want to do would be to poll using a loop, again, you need to read up on event-driven programming since your polling idea goes against how you use it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a while loop. Swing is event driven once you create and make a JFrame visible the frame will stay open until the user closes the frame.

Also, if you need child windows, then you should be using a JDialog, not another JFrame.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) for a simple example to get you started.

Comment: Yes I understand that. The point of the while loop is to check the instance field of another class and then to dispose of that frame. For example If that method (which is an accessor method) returns true it will close the frame.  The system println are just to find out if the while loop even executes which it doesn't...

Comment: `The point of the while loop is to check the instance field of another class and then to dispose of that frame` - that logic should NOT be in the main() method. That logic should be in the class when the instance variable is changed. Then when the variable is changed you close the window.